# Java(TM) Platform SE Binary has stopped working (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running a java program in eclipse. The program goes through a directory of subdirectories full of sqlback files from an android app and for each file, parses it and makes an entry into different collections of a mongo db depending on the data.

Everything was functioning fine. All mongo data had been verified and the I was asked to deal with some corrupted files. In handling the sqlite files I added some validation checks, but I did not change the logic flow of my program. I can now identify corrupted files, horray. BUT after I run my program I get an Error:

Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working.

A second pop up window states that "Files that help describe the problem" and then lists files on a path that actually does not exist.

I am looking for a lead on how to how to debug this error. The error happens about 500 files deep into the 30th directory, so debugging is not really that much of a sane option.

Thanks in advance,

Miss Serena

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.
I just changed the name of my previous workspace and it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your Eclipse project (push F5)...its possible its our of sync with your file system...also try to restart Eclipse.

Another way would be creating a new java project and copying your classes there...and then try to run from the newly created project.

Comment: I actually refreshed, cleaned, restarted and recopied. Unfortunately no luck. I did figure out that those files must be hidden. I was under the misconception that hidden files were prefixed with a ".".

Comment: When I examined the files I can see that there are issues with my sqlite dll file. I did a very comprehensive examination of my data set and it seems that the one file that it consistently dies on is an sqlite file with hundreds of thousands of records. It dwarfs the the other files. I put in an arbitrary check so that if the sqlite file has > 100000 to skip these files (they should never be this large, and it turns out the fact that it is is a bug that carried through to the data from the android app dev). Now it works. Its a bit of a hack though

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same Issue and solved it after changing the version of the JDK from 1.8u181 to 1.8u191 I think its something corrupted with the the JDK Version

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and my solution was to delete Oracle folder in your Program Files\Common Files
After that, uninstall the current JDK and reinstall that. Hope it works for you.